# Calculating the Running ratio in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data like this:

```
col1 value
A     10
B     9
C     7   
D     6
```

I want to calculate the ratios to the previous item

```
col1 value
A     9/10
B     7/9
C     6/7
D
```

How can I do this with SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: You have to define 'previous'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`lead()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead):

```
SELECT col1, value / lead(value) over (order by col1)
FROM t;
```